# How to implement GRiS mean and deviation

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I am dealing with skewness in a data set and wanted to use a modern approach. I came across a recent paper which used the *Golden Ratio in Statistics* (**GRiS**):

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314032599_TO_DETERMINE_SKEWNESS_MEAN_AND_DEVIATION_WITH_A_NEW_APPROACH_ON_CONTINUOUS_DATA

I am currently trying to write the formulas in python and am having difficulty getting the accurate numbers they depict in the paper using a red wine quality data set.

For the GRiS mean, left deviation, and right deviation I am getting (respectively):

1. 8.334
2. -0.356
3. 1.168

When I should be getting:

1. 8.223
2. -1.250
3. 2.060

I have posted the code below which follows the format the formulas are presented in the article. The red wine quality set is available from:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("winequality-red.csv", sep = ";")

column = "fixed acidity"
# mean coefficients
Mc = []

# weighted deviation from medium
WDfM = []

median = data[column].median()
n = data.shape[0]

# sort into ascending order of column
data = data.sort_values(by = column)

# mean of GRiS coefficients 
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # add 1 to index to start index at 1
    if data[column].loc[i] < median:
        Mc.append(1 / ((1 + np.sqrt(5)) / 2) + 2 * (i + 1 - 1) / (n - 1))
    else:
        Mc.append(1 + ((1 + np.sqrt(5)) / 2) - 2 * (i + 1 - 1) / (n - 1))

# deviation from medium
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # weighted distances from median
    WDfM.append(Mc[i] * (data[column].loc[i] - median))
    
# sum of WDfM
WDfM_sum = sum(WDfM)
    
# sum of Mci
Mc_sum = sum(Mc)

# GRiS median deviation
GRiS_median_D = WDfM_sum / Mc_sum

# GRiS mean
GRiS_mean = median + GRiS_median_D

# Deviation
k = 0
Dc = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    if data[column].loc[i] < GRiS_mean:
        k += 1
        
# coefficients        
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    if data[column].loc[i] < GRiS_mean:
        Dc.append(((1 + np.sqrt(5)) / 2) - (i + 1 - 1) / (k - 1))
    else:
        Dc.append(((1 + np.sqrt(5)) / 2) - (i + 1 - k - 1) / (n - k - 1))


Dc_right = []
Dc_left = []

# GRiS deviations
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    if data[column].loc[i] < GRiS_mean:
        Dc_left.append(Dc[i] * (data[column].loc[i] - GRiS_mean))
    
    elif data[column].loc[i] > GRiS_mean:
        Dc_right.append(Dc[i] * (data[column].loc[i] - GRiS_mean))

Dc_sum = sum(Dc)
Dc_left_sum = sum(Dc_left)
Dc_right_sum = sum(Dc_right)

GRiS_D_left = (Dc_left_sum / Dc_sum)
GRiS_D_right = (Dc_right_sum / Dc_sum) 

print(GRiS_mean)
print(GRiS_D_left)
print(GRiS_D_right)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the corresponding author of the paper,

First of all, thank you very much for your interest. I am not a coding expert, but I can provide two codes (C# and MATLAB) and also an online calculator. Also, new python code is developed and linked below;

http://www.goldenratioinstatistics.com/calculate.aspx

https://github.com/guvengunver/GRiSTEN/

https://pypi.org/project/golden-ratio-stats/

I hope they would be helpful

sincerely